# How do divide a number with right Bit shift by non power of 2

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I need to divide a number by 12 using bit shift operations. With multiplication, you can add powers of 2 until you arrive at the desired number, however that approach does not seem to be applicable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well know solution from [Hackers Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf) by using shift operation

```
unsigned divu12(unsigned n) {
 unsigned q, r;
 q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 3);
 q = q + (q >> 4);
 q = q + (q >> 8);
 q = q + (q >> 16);
 q = q >> 3;
 r = n - q*12;
 return q + ((r + 4) >> 4);
// return q + (r > 11);
}
```

Hope this helps you